# Usability of power series in AI analysis

Tags: math, applications, academia

In mathematics, [power series](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/PowerSeries.aspx) is given by

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (x-a)^n$$

where $c_n , a \in \mathbb{R}$

Although most of the courses in academics cover *moment generating functions* in probability theory for AI, which is power series by itself, I didn't encounter yet an application or analysis that contains power series in either textbooks or research papers.

So, I want to know whether the power series has any usability in any branch of AI.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a TaylorSwiftNet ([Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.14392)). They model a (finite) Taylor series to predict the evolution of the hidden state, and a decoder to predict the observed state in a future time step.

> In this work, we therefore propose to approximate the motion in a
> video by a continuous function using the Taylor series. To this end,
> we introduce TayloSwiftNet, a novel convolutional neural network that
> learns to estimate the higher order terms of the Taylor series for a
> given input video. TayloSwiftNet can swiftly predict any desired
> future frame in just one forward pass and change the temporal
> resolution on-the-fly. The experimental results on various datasets
> demonstrate the superiority of our model.

[image]